# First application with wit ai

Tags: wit-ai

I am working on a chat application with wit-ai. I have created a hello world but I am not getting how to provide my function with have business logic to the application.

Help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the [quickstart](https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart)? There is a section (#6) on "Implementing the business logic of the bot".
Basically the business logic resides in your app.
The SDKs on github provide also a few examples (e.g. [NodeJS](https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit/tree/master/examples)).

Hope this helps!